# Add image on when click input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do:

- after clicking plus sign, insert image instead of plus sign
- create new plus sign after added image

My codepen demo:
[CodePen](https://codepen.io/heybetov1998/pen/LzwvMN)

```
function readImage(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('.cert img').attr('src', e.target.result);
      $('.cert label').css('opacity', '0');
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are not loading jQuery in your CodePen project? Go to the JS config panel and do a quick add and try it again.

Comment: I added right now

Comment: I added Bootstrap too

Comment: You are generating multiple divs that have the same structure, so each one has the same ID (which is not legal) but each also has the same structure that will match your selector `.cert img`, so they are all updated at the same time with the new image as you load it.

Comment: I want to add number after Id name with JS

Comment: if you want you can delete id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't quite perfect, but it works to load multiple images and does clean up the duplicated ID.  You can try it in your CodePen JS box:

```
function readImage(input, element) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $(element).find("img").attr("src", e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#certImg0").change(function() {
  var element = $(this)
    .parent()
    .clone();
  $(element).find('input').remove();
  $(element).find('label').remove();
  element.insertAfter($(this).parent());
  readImage(this, element);
});
```

The intent of this is to take the element that is generated and pass the actual element that was created to the `readImage` function and the new image that is loaded is directly stored in the `img` element on the new div structure.

(This could be optimized to generate only the div with the `img` element, and that would make it so that the new images are not clickable.  In fact, I modified the code to do that- deleting the input and label from the cloned element.)

Comment: Could you take the time to explain what your code does and how it solves the problem? If you could also explain why the original code didn't work that would be welcome too.